# Validating user input in authorization header (node.js express-validator)

Tags: javascript, validation, node.js

I am using Node.js and express-validator to validate user input server-side. The form I am controlling is simple to validate, by ensuring that constraints are being met such as "isInt" and "isFloat", "isBoolean" etc.

I guess I must also check the authorization header. It is submitted in the login form as basic auth, through the authorization header. So the header looks like this for example:

```
Basic dGhhbmtzZm9ydGFraW5nOnRpbWVoZWxwaW5nbWU6KQ==
```

Using https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator **I would really appreciate any help on the strategy on how to validate the input here.**

In order to extract the username and password I use

```
var auth = require('basic-auth'); //and
var info = auth(req); //getting info.user and info.pass
```

I am also curious whether this does any input validation by default. The documentation of basic-auth says

> **auth(req)** Get the basic auth credentials from the given request. The
>   Authorization header is parsed and **if the header is invalid,** undefined
>   is returned, otherwise an object with name and pass properties.

I am not sure what this means - invalid in what way etc. It would be neat if this does sufficient validation in itself, but I doubt it.

Main question is **how to "clean" this from injection attacks and scripts.** It is base64 encoded, so I guess I would have to decode it and then clean it. But maybe that poses som risk in itself?

**Any help on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: I am a bit new to this particular forum. Maybe I will move this question, or copy it, to other main forums. It seems activity is a bit lower here maybe.